Unable to start MYSQL server in Ubuntu 22.04 LTE
I installed MySQL in my ubuntu 22.04 LTE environment but I am unable to get the server started. I am getting a

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

I have tried to purge and reinstall, I have tried to edit the .cnf file with the following
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[client]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

I used the digital ocean docs to install, using sudo apt install mysql-server... I purged the previous copy along with Maria because they were installed with me running Ubuntu as the admin (root). I am now getting this error:
sudo service mysql start
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory


mysql is the client. You need to also install and configure mysqld, the server.

I used the digital ocean docs to install, using sudo apt install mysql-server....I purged the previous copy along with Maria because they were installed with me running Ubuntu as the admin (root). I am now getting this error, "sudo service mysql start

Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory"


Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

If you don't have anything important on your database, I recommend you to do some cleanup and reinstall the MySQL server.
Warning: These commands will delete all your data stored on the MySQL server!
sudo apt purge mysql-*
sudo apt purge mariadb-*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql

Install MySQL:
sudo apt install mysql-server

